# Prompting User Each Loop Iteration

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

The purpose of this code is to use a `for` loop to ask the user for a name 5 times, each time storing said name into the position in an array.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    char names[5];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter a name: ";
        getline(cin, names[i]);
        cout<<endl;
    } 

    cout << names[5]; 
    return 0; 
}
```

This is the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, char&)’
 getline(cin, names[i]);
```

I changed it to just a regular `cin` operator, even though I'm not supposed to do that, and it compiled but the loop just iterated 5 times without prompting the user for anything, and this was the result:

```
Enter a name: 
Enter a name: 
Enter a name: 
Enter a name: 
Enter a name:
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant an array of 5 elements of type `std::string`:

```
std::string names[5];
```

and, then use a loop to print the names also like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    string names[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter a name: ";
        getline(cin, names[i]);
        cout << endl;
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << names[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`char names[5];` is an array of `5` characters. It can contain strings up to `4` characters long, because there needs to be space for the terminating null character.

For strings you should be using `std::string` and for an array of fixed size of strings you should be using `std::array<std::string,5>` (`std::vector` when the size is not a compile time constant).

Correct code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
int main ()  {

    std::array<std::string,5> names;   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) {      
        std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, names[i]);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }   
    std::cout << names[4];   // names[5]; is the 6th element which was out-of-bounds !    
}
```

In the last line you attempted to print `names[5]` but there is not 6th element in `names`, valid indices are `0` up to including `size - 1`.